# FASM SHR strange behaviour

Tags: linux, assembly

Using FASM I'm trying to shift dword with a `SHR` instruction which should shift bits to right appending zeroes. Here is the code:

```
format ELF executable 3

entry start

segment readable executable

start:
    cmp byte [counter],0
    jz fin

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,some
    mov edx,4
    int 0x80 ; write 4 bytes

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,splitter
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80 ; write a split byte (0x42)

    shr dword [some],4

    dec byte [counter]
    jmp start
fin:
    mov eax,1
    xor ebx,ebx
    int 0x80

segment readable writeable

some db 0x89,0xAB,0xCD,0xEF
splitter db 0x42
counter db 10
```

I expected to get something like that: `0x89ABCDEF -> 0x089ABCDE -> 0x0089ABCD -> 0x00089ABC -> 0x000089AB -> 0x0000089A -> 0x00000089 -> 0x00000008 -> 0x00000000`
But I get this instead: `0x89ABCDEF -> 0xB8DAFC0E -> 0xABCDEF00 -> 0xDAFC0E00 -> 0xCDEF0000 -> 0xFC0E0000 -> 0xEF000000 -> 0x0E000000 -> 0x00000000`

What am I doing wrong?

P. S. This values were gotten by opening the file in which I redirect the output in hex editor. (It's not the output itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers are stored little endian.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

To clarify,
0x89ABCDEF is stored as 0xEFCDAB89, so right shift produces 0x0EFCDAB8, which is the bytes you see, in reverse order

Comment: Either your printing or your hex editor is doing an implicit reversal of byte order.  Basically the bytes you are "seeing" are the reverse order of the bytes your are right shifting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wrote `SHR` between `BSWAP`'s and not it works good. But I'm not sure that it was the best way...